# A 2018-DMM-Team Round-10 Question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Yikai wants to know Liang’s secret code which is a 6-digit integer x. Furthermore, let d(n) denote the
digital sum of a positive integer n. For instance, $d(14) = 5$ and $d(3) = 3$. It is given that
$x + d(x) + d(d(x)) + d(d(d(x))) = 999868$

Any one have solution?Thanks.

Comment: The digital sum is like a logarithm because the number of digits is the base $10$ log of the number and each digit is at most $9$.  That means it decreases quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**: Clearly, $x \le x+d(x)+d(d(x))+d(d(d(x))) = 999868$.

Hence, $d(x) \le 9+9+9+7+9+9 = 52$, $d(d(x)) \le 4+9 = 13$, and $d(d(d(x))) \le 9$.

So, $x = 999868-d(x)-d(d(x))-d(d(d(x))) \ge 999868-52-13-9 = 999794$.

This gives you a small range to search for.

Also, you can use the fact that $d(n) \equiv n \pmod{9}$ for all positive integers $n$, to determine $x \pmod{9}$ This should narrow down your search to only a small number of possible values of $x$.